# Xamarin System.objectmodel

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble creating a xaml shared project.  Out of the box creating a new project it will not compile.  Seems to be related to system.objectmodel, manually added it from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades

Same thing; not found.  I tried removing the reference, no difference.

I am also getting a conflict warning, for system.runtime

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ObjectModel" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I hope this is simple.  All I have done is create a new xamarin xaml shared project and tried to compile it and it fails.  I just don't know the secret-sauce and which assemblies and their locations to use, need a little help to get past this.

Thanks much,

~David

Environment Info:
Windows 10 Home
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586
Installed Version: Community
Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA015
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015
Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA015
Microsoft Visual C# 2015
Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA015
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
Command Bus, Event Stream and Async Manager   Merq
Provides ICommandBus, IEventStream and IAsyncManager MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.
Common Azure Tools   1.8
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
GitHub.VisualStudio   1.0
A Visual Studio Extension that brings the GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service
JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

TypeScript   1.8.36.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

Xamarin   4.2.0.703 (3b7df6f)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android   7.0.1.3 (96c7ba6)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS   10.0.1.10 (ad1cd42)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Installing it from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ObjectModel/) might be better than manually adding a reference

Comment: Tried it....  Updating the packages creates a circular reference with xamarin.forms.  First pass, updates to 24....  but then wants to downgrade forms 23.3 after the update, then it calls for the update to 24 again, my head is going to explode...   never touches system.objectmodel anyway which is expected, thats is a ms assembly.  What version, I am not sure... 4.2?  What a can of worms.  I think the wheels fell off updating xamarin to 4.2 via tools...  Xamarin wants me to burn an msdn incident to get this working, lol..

Answer (score 0):

First , Remove some file from your computer, C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Local\Xamarin

Second,Update Java Version.

3. Go to [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ObjectModel/://) update the latest version of System.ObjectModel

All the Problems and solutions I had write in My [Blog](http://cheahengsoon.weebly.com/blog/solve-javalangobjectclass-in-xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

Try *Build, Clean Solution* and manually delete the *bin* and *obj* folder in your solution. (Both PCL and Android/iOS)
In the end give a try to restart Visual Studio too